# Firefox: Running external programs on click

Tags: raspberry-pi, firefox, youtube

Is there a way to make firefox stream youtube videos in an external player (eg vlc) when you click on a youtube video?  More generally, is it possible to run an external script upon clicking certain types of links, eg those that are of the form www.youtube.com/watch?v=* ?

Even more ambitiously, when I click on a youtube video while pressing down CTRL, I want to automatically ssh into my raspberry pi and stream the video on the pi with omxplayer.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you could try to have a look to the settings of firefox and see if you can set a given MIME type to be open in an external software.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily what you require is issuing an external command on your OS from your browser. But this is usually tough due to obvious security reasons. However, there is an add-on for Firefox which can achieve this : [Commandrun](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/commandrun/). But I haven't tried this addon so can't comment on it.

### A Reasonably Good Solution

However, I'd suggest another alternative solution using `Autokey`. This is not going to be the best solution as per your needs but it can be a reasonable one.

So, first install autokey:

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk #Assuming you're on a Debian-based linux
```

Now, in `Autokey`, create a new script and write the following lines in that script:

```python
import subprocess
keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+l") #Bring cursor to the location bar
time.sleep(0.15)
keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+c") #Now copy the location from the location bar
time.sleep(0.15)
keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+w") #Now close the window
time.sleep(0.15)

text = clipboard.get_selection() #copy the clipboard content i.e. the URL

subprocess.call(["vlc", text]) #Make the call to vlc player
```

Now, assign some hotkey to this script such as <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> or anything else that you prefer. Also, assign a filter so that this script will run only on Firefox windows and not any other window. To apply the filter just add `.*Firefox.*` in the Filter.

#### How this works:

Whenever you are on a youtube video page on Firefox, you can now press <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and this script will run. It will first copy the url and then close the youtube tab. Then it will take this url and make a call to vlc to run this video.

#### Further extension

You can further easily extend the script to make an ssh connection to your RaspberryPi and run the video there.